# Adding a class or style to a disabled button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am disabling a button until atleast one checkbox has been selected like so:

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='button']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

My buttons initial state is disabled but I need it to be like faded out or opacity added to it, im not sure what the best approach would be either do it with adding a class or just adding CSS? im not really sure?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Are you trying to make the button look disabled when it isn't disabled, or...?

Comment: Side note: Although jQuery will fix it for you if you do what's above, the correct way to set the `disabled` property is either `.prop("disabled", booleanFlagHere)`, or if you want to use `attr` then setting it to any string to set the flag or using `removeAttr` to remove it. (But `prop` is simpler.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no the button IS disabled UNTIL a checkbox has been checked/selected. So the button is to appear disabled and then appear enabled once the action has taken place.

Comment: To style a disabled element, you can use the following CSS selectors `elementTag:disabled {/* CSS */}` or `elementTag[disabled] {/* CSS */}` but as T.J.Crowder noted: it's difficult to interpret your question as to what, specifically, you want to do. It may be worth having a read of "*[ask]*" for additional pointers.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks guys it makes sense, Thanks TJ for pointing out a better method, and thanks David for the CSS tip off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to adjust the appearance of a disabled button, you do that with a CSS [attribute presence](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation) selector (`input[type=button][disabled]`) or a CSS [`:disabled` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#enableddisabled) selector (`input[type=button]:disabled`):

```
input[type=button][disabled] {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
/* or: */
input[type=button]:disabled {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The attribute selector works because a disabled button has a `disabled` attribute, and an enabled one does not. But in modern code, I'd probably use `:disabled` instead.

Example:

```js
var btn = $("#toggle");
setInterval(function() {
  btn.prop("disabled", !btn.prop("disabled"));
}, 1000);
```

```css
/* Here I've used each of the two possible options
   to provide half of the styling you wanted.
   You'd obviously just choose one of them and use
   it to handle both parts of the styling.
*/
input[type=button][disabled] {
    color: red;
}
input[type=button]:disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="This is enabled">
<input type="button" disabled value="This is disabled">
<input id="toggle" type="button" value="This one goes back and forth">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can add the styling:

```
<button class="btn-disabled" disabled> Test </button>

button:disabled.btn-disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

$("button").addClass( "btn-disabled" );
```